# How to update UI thread from coroutines background thread?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have got a function displayDirectoryContents2(file: File) which scans all the file and check for files and directories. What I want is to display the current file path in a textview in UI thread

```
lateinit var textView: TextView


GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
 displayDirectoryContents2(file)
}
```

Code for the function

```
private fun displayDirectoryContents2(dir: File?){
    try {
        val files = dir?.listFiles()!!

        files.forEach {

            if (it.isDirectory) {
                displayDirectoryContents2(it)
            } else { 
                   if (it.isFile) {
                    textView.text = it.name // to Update the file name in UI thread
              }
        }


    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I am new to Kotlin Coroutines. Actually I want to run function displayDirectoryContents2(file: File) in background thread and update the name of the file the function is reading in UI thread just like AsyncTask.

Comment: You can switch context to Main (`withContext(Dispatchers.Main){}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either switch dispatcher contexts (Dispatchers.IO for the logic, then to Dispatchers.Main for updating the UI), or you can move your code into a ViewModel and there use the same context switching technique or use postvalue() of LiveData. An example of doing the latter below. You can read on ViewModel here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData 
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val files: MutableLiveData<List<String>> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    }
    fun loadFiles(path: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(){
            doLoadFiles()
        }
    }
    private suspend fun doLoadFiles() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val results = listOf("patha", "pathb")//replace with your actual code
            files.postValue(results)
        }
    }
    fun getFiles(): LiveData<List<String>> = files
}
```

Then call it like this from your activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val model = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[MyViewModel::class.java]
        model.getFiles().observe(this, Observer<List<String>>{ paths ->
            // update UI
            println (paths)
        })
        model.loadFiles("S")

    }
```

In your build.gradle file, make sure to import the relevant dependencies

```
 def lifecycle_ver = "2.2.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_ver"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_ver"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_ver"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make `displayDirectoryContents2` suspended function and then use `withContext` to switch context.

```
suspend fun displayDirectoryContents2() {
    ...
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        textView.text = it.name
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to approach this is to first create a function that returns a `Flow<String>` of filenames that executes itself on the `IO` dispatcher:

```
fun File.filenameFlow() = flow<String> { traverseAndEmit(this@filenameFlow) }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)

private suspend fun FlowCollector<String>.traverseAndEmit(dir: File) {
    dir.listFiles()?.forEach {
        when {
            it.isDirectory -> traverseAndEmit(it)
            it.isFile -> emit(it.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply `collect` it at any point in the GUI thread without blocking:

```
File("target").filenameFlow().collect { textView.text = it }
```

Answer (score 2):

do the scanning of the files off the main thread using the `suspend` function.

```
suspend fun loadFiles(): List<String> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
// code for getting the files 
return@withContext list }
```

once that's done, update the UI thread using `lifecycleScope.launch{ }` in `onCreate()` fun of the activity.  As shown below

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    lifecycleScope.launch { // Dispatchers.Main
        textView.text = loadFiles()[i]
    }
}
```